# There is no cells showing in my jupyter notebook. How can I fix it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

[Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnXwE.png)

NOt able to write code because there is no cells.

Answer (score 0):

You should click on the plus icon up there. It will create a new cell for you

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: You should try closing the jupyter instance and start again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a cell from the Insert menu in the menu bar.